# Chrome/Safari CSS problem z-index or float?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I have a site http://pintum.com.au/goCruising/

I am using [Easy Slider 1.7](http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider) 
with a few custom JS changes for a banner rotator.

My problem is on webkit the navigation links 1,2,3,4,5 on the banner ad are not clickable. When I click them the underlying image hyper-link to a different page is activated instead of changing the index of the image in the slider.

Using firefox and IE8 the slider links work as expected.

For anyone extra keen to help.  In Firefox the CSS  -moz-border-radius: 20px; is not being applied to the banner either?  But that however does work on webkit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position:relative;` to the list items of the `.controls` list, that should to the trick.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. =) Any idea why moz-border-radius: 20px; is not being applied to the banner in Firefox?